# Is there a way to echo/cat a multiline message in Fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

In Bash/Zsh, it is Okay using cat for a multiline message, eg:

```
cat <<DELIM
This is line 1
This is line 2
DELIM
```

However, the above code does not work for Fish Shell.
Is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I ended up using for my block of text.  Read the tip about printf from faho.  But wanted the code to be looking like the block itself.

```
printf "\t%s\n"              \
       "###################" \
       "#                 #" \
       "# Multiline block #" \
       "#                 #" \
       "###################"
```

%s: Is the strings encapsulated in double quotes.

\n: New line.

\t: Horizontal tab.

Mixing it together inserts a tab before each line, indenting the text.  And it adds a carriage return at the end of each line.

Comment: Great answer! Though a little late, I'd refactory my code accordingly

Answer (score 12):

Fish doesn't have "[Here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells)".

The easiest way to do this is probably to use `printf`, e.g.:

```
printf "%s\n" "This is line 1" "This is line 2"
```

Or you can take advantage of the fact that fish scans for matching quotes across multiple lines:

```
echo "This is line 1
This is line 2"
```

If you wish to have the ending quote on the next line to ease inserting more lines, you can use `echo -n`:

```
echo -n "This is line 1
This is line 2
"
```